# Customize communication with Spring Boot login page

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to create custom communication with Spring Boot login page (e.g. I don't want page to reload after bad credentials are provided), but I don't know how to do that. 
In other pages I have a button which communicates my application through AJAX:

```
button.click(function(e){
    //some magic
    $ajax.({
        //some more magic
    }).done(responseObj => {
        //some magic with response
    });
})
```

And in `//some magic with response` I can change some components on page based on reponse value e.g. on password change page I can show jumbotron at the middle of the screen that password cannot be changed, because provided old password is not equal to an existing one. And let's say that I want to do a similiar thing to a login page, but here (when user provides wrong credentials) I want jumbotron to show that credentials are invalid. The problem is that I don't have an access to what happens when i click button. I have 
`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        //some not needed code
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/guest/login")
        //some more not needed code
}
```

and login form code:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" placeholder="Login">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="buttonLogin" type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
</form>
```

and I don't (or even i can't) do anything with what happens beneath. I suspect that I need to delete `method="post"` from code above, but I don't know how to communicate with Spring Boot login logic then. Can someone explain it to me?